# fastboot command

Tags: android, boot, fastboot

I am able to run fastboot commands via command prompt on my Windows machine when the phone is booted into fastboot manually by holding: volume up + volume down + power

**Is there a way in Android to programmically boot into fastboot and run the command without the need of using an external machine to push commands?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's not.  The closest you can do is wipe the phone and reset it to factory settings using an intent, but I suspect that isn't what you're looking for.

Comment: Is there any third party `.jar` or option to do this? Or if I manually boot into fastboot is there a way to emulate the pc commands if I have the kernel stored locally?

Comment: You need to be connected to something via the USB port.  Once you do that, you can easily enter fastboot and send images, data, etc.